# Illegal format string in TextIO.putf() method aka wrong Array Type?

Tags: java, arrays

I guess its a rather simple question but i just cant find my mistake.

```
int[]   myIntArray = new int[20];

myIntArray[5] = 5;      
int a = myIntArray[5];
TextIO.putf("arr[i]: d%",a );
```

The error I get is Illegal format string in TextIO.putf() method.

So I assume the value at the index 5 is not an int?

Comment: Where the hell is "minimal understanding" option?? I desperately need it.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun This one at least shows an attempt. It's not gold-badge question, but format strings can be hard to get at first.

Comment: o my i realised it seconds after myself. sry to bother you guys. ill go and be ashamed for a while.  thx alot anyways tough..

Answer (score 1):

The error message says exactly what the problem is: your format string is wrong. You probably meant `%d` (or better yet, `%d%n` to add a newline).

Answer (score 1):

The format string elements are in the form

```
%[modifiers]type
```

not

```
something%
```

Change `d%` to `%d`.